# TFS and RoboHelp 10 ImageSize.Width Error and "Cannot find file" when Adding New Topic

Tags: tfs, robohelp

We have integrated RoboHelp 10 with TFS. Authoring environment: Windows 7 Enterprise, SP1). There are two authors. One of us has no trouble checking in files and creating new files. **Problem 1:** The second author can check in one file (per RoboHelp session), but after that gets the following error in RoboHelp on attempts to check in:

> Value of '272' is not valid for 'ImageSize.Width'. 'ImageSize.Width'
>   should be between 1 and 256. Parameter name: ImageSize.

No such parameter exists in the files. Though inconvenient, there is a workaround: check in using the Source Control Explorer. **Problem 2** is more serious. The second author can create a new help topic once. After that, TFS will not allow a check in and the topic does not get created (i.e., no file is created in Robo). Error reads:

> "Could not find file '[filepath and name]'."

Question: Has anyone encountered Problem 2 and if so, what's to be done? (Problem 1 may provide some context, hence its inclusion here.)

Answer (score 1):

Problem 1 - Change DPI font to 96 (100%) at control panel.